# truffle init truffle : File C:\Users\PC-Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, cryptocurrency

`PS H:\BlockChain\dev\VS Code\ethereum\web> truffle init truffle : File C:\Users\PC-NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\truffle.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.`

Answer (score 2):

try using --> `npx truffle init` , for initiating project
`npx truffle compile` , for compilation, it worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in windows power shell
   >> 'Set-ExecutionPol[enter image description here][1]icy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser'

Answer (score 0):

**1. Run PowerShell as an administrator**
2. After that run the following command:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

3.Then run the command for truffle:
`npm install -g truffle`

Now everything will work perfectly including (`truffle init`).Though I recommend you to use `truffle unbox` instead of `truffle init`

If you still get errors then let me know. I have different solutions in it.